# How can I disable running unsigned binaries in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, security, sign

I would like to replicate an error a client is receiving 'access is denied' on Powershell when they run my binary. Seems like they have some restrictions. I don't know what are there actual restrictions. I tried to block unsigned apps from 'Local Security Policy' and 'App & Browser Control', however I am still able to run unsigned binary in my Powershell (not run as Administrator).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's hard to troubleshoot with the executable.

Comment: Binary or script?

Comment: If you made the binary on one computer, then copied it to another computer, it may contain some kind of signature that identifies it as downloaded.  That is enough to trigger a security restriction.  Sorry, but I don't know the particulars.

Comment: It's a binary. Actually two binaries: an exe file and an msi file that contains the exe.